# MongoDB - How to find a record if today date is greater than 3 days added to a date field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If there are documents with `endDate`, I want to fetch documents in a collection whose endDate + 3 days is less than today through the Mongo query.

The below query will find records whose `endDate` is less than today.

```js
const myCollection = DB_CONNECTION.collection(TRANSACTION);

let expiredTrans = await myCollection.find({ "endDate": { $lt: curTime}}).toArray();
```

I need to add 3 days to the `endDate` and then fetch records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`$dateAdd`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/) operator, but since it is an aggregation operator, you need to work with the `$expr` operator.

Optional, you can replace `curTime` with `$$NOW` which is a MongoDB variable to get the current time.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      {
        $dateAdd: {
          startDate: "$endDate",
          unit: "day",
          amount: 3
        }
      },
      "$$NOW"// curTime
      
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TIct_LrUxeF)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
let expiredTrans = await myCollection.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      { $add: ["$endDate", 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000] }, // Add 3 days in milliseconds
      "$$NOW"// curTime
    ]
  }
}).toArray();
```